# Event firing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have a tab contol with two tabs. Each one containing listviews. When the selection change event of listview is fired, the selection change of tabcontrol is also fired. How can I prevent this?

Comment: If you are selecting the list view in the unselected tab then I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Handled property of the EventArgs object to true when you are done with the listview event so it wont route further up the tree...

```
e.Handled = true;
```

HTH

Comment: My first assumption was that the events were independent, when they're clearly not.

Comment: Nope, it is the same event.. It doesn't check the original source.. So its always a good idea to set your event on handled when you are done with it, to avoid suprises ;)..